# How do I increment or decrement a number in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, increment, decrement

What is the *idiomatic* Common Lisp way to increment/decrement numbers and/or numeric variables?

Answer (score 43):

Use the built-in "+" or "-" functions, or their shorthand "1+" or "1-", if you just want to use the result, without modifying the original number (the argument). If you do want to modify the original place (containing a number), then use the built-in "incf" or "decf" functions.

Using the addition operator:

```
(setf num 41)
(+ 1 num)   ; returns 42, does not modify num
(+ num 1)   ; returns 42, does not modify num
(- num 1)   ; returns 40, does not modify num
(- 1 num)   ; NOTE: returns -40, since a - b is not the same as  b - a
```

Or, if you prefer, you could use the following short-hand:

```
(1+ num)    ; returns 42, does not modify num.
(1- num)    ; returns 40, does not modify num.
```

Note that the Common Lisp specification defines the above two forms to be equivalent in meaning, and suggests that implementations make them equivalent in performance. While this is a suggestion, according to Lisp experts, any "self-respecting" implementation should see no performance difference.

If you wanted to update num (not just get 1 + its value), then use "incf":

```
(setf num 41)
(incf num)  ; returns 42, and num is now 42.

(setf num 41)
(decf num)  ; returns 40, and num is now 40.

(incf 41)   ; FAIL! Can't modify a literal
```

NOTE:

You can also use incf/decf to increment (decrement) by more than 1 unit:

```
(setf foo 40)
(incf foo 2.5)  ; returns 42.5, and foo is now 42.5
```

For more information, see the Common Lisp Hyperspec:
[1+](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm)
[incf/decf](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_incf_.htm#incf)